# CSS3 background - incomplete spec?

Tags: css

In Chrome right now, the background style spec:

`background: color position/size repeat origin clip attachment image|initial|inherit;`

But I cannot get the `position/size` fragment to work;

I should be able to say `red top left 100% 100% no-repeat url()` or `red top left contain url()` or even `red contain url()` -- but none of these render results.

Of course I can do it by specifying the individual `background-*` attributes. Is the spec broken or Chrome?? O_o

Comment: What do You want to accomplish and why You don't want to use `background-*` attributes?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos I do not want to use the -* attribs. It looks like a single statement cannot specify both position and size since they are indistinguishable unless the position of arguments is brought into play -- though `contain` and `cover` could play well with positions. An anomaly?

Answer (score 0):

CSS `background` attribute syntax is like this:

```
background: [  <background-color>    ||  <background-image>       ||
               <background-repeat>   ||  <background-attachment>  ||
               <background-position>
            ]   |   inherit ;
```

example:

```
background: red url("../images/image.jpg") no-repeat scroll top left;
```

As for `background-size` attribute, it's from CSS3. You should use it separately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. You are missing the `/` between `position` and `size`:

```
background: #FFF url("/image/path/img.jpg) no-repeat scroll top left / 100% 100%;
                                                                     ^
```

Example:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #FFF url(http://placehold.it/400x400) no-repeat scroll top left / 100% 100%;
}
```